# Servlet does not print messages on console

Tags: java, servlets

sorry for silly mistakes I have made. I am following example from "java for web with servlets, jsp and ejb" book
So I have the following problem. I have a servlet. The function of the servlet is very simple - just retrieve request parameters and print them on console.The servlet is called from inside index.html file.
The code for the index.html file is

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> sending a request</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action=RequestDemoServlet method="POST">
        <br> <br>
    Author: <input type="TEXT" name="author">
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit">
    <input type="RESET" value="reset">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code for the servlet is following

```
 import javax.servlet.*;
 import java.util.Enumeration;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public class RequestDemoServlet implements Servlet
 {
     public void init(ServletConfig config) 
        throws ServletException
     {}
     public void destroy()
     {}
     public void service(ServletRequest request,
            ServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
     {
         System.out.println("Server port: "+request.getServerPort());
         System.out.println("Server name: "+request.getServerName());
         System.out.println("Protocol: "+request.getProtocol());
         System.out.println("Char encoding: "+
                request.getCharacterEncoding());
         System.out.println("Constent length: "+
                request.getContentLength());
         System.out.println("Remote address: "+
                request.getRemoteAddr());
         System.out.println("remote Host: "+request.getRemoteHost());
         Enumeration parameters=request.getParameterNames();
         while(parameters.hasMoreElements())
         {
             String parameterName=(String)parameters.nextElement();
             System.out.println("Parameter name: "+parameterName);
             System.out.println("Parameter value: "+
                    request.getParameter(parameterName));
         }
    }
     public String getServletInfo()
     {
         return null;
     }
     public ServletConfig getServletConfig()
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

I compiled the RequestDemoSevlet.java with javac as in

```
javac -cp $CATALINA_HOME/lib/servlet-api.jar -d ./classes RequestDemoServelt.java
```

The .class file for the servlet is put into the classes directory of my application.
Then I edited web.xml file

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns.xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http:/java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>Chapter 2</display-name>
    <description> Apress</description>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RequestDemo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>RequestDemoServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
</web-app>
```

I suppose that I made a mistake either in web.xml or index.html files. Can somebody help me with the problem?

Comment: Define _console_.

Comment: linux terminal in my case

Comment: And why do you think it should print there?

Comment: I guess that System.out.println() prints on console

Comment: What servlet container are you using?

Comment: @olzhabala, your servlet's `System.out` is not necessarily connected to a terminal.  The servlet container may well have provided a different terminus.  Moreover, there is also the question of *which* terminal you hope to see the output upon; the only plausible one is the servlet container's controlling terminal, if it has one.  Consider also whether the servlet container's standard output may be redirected to a file.

Comment: @olzhabala Ensure that your servlet-mapping is correct as shown below first, otherwise there will not be any requests served by the servlet

Comment: Why does it print into catalina.out file?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis apache tomcat